# How Do I Run xUnit.NET Unit Tests in Monodevelop?

Tags: unit-testing, monodevelop, linux-mint, xunit.net

How do I run xUnit.net unit tests from Monodevelop?  I have version 5.9.6 installed on LMDE and have installed the xUnit.NET testing framework support Add-In.  I have a test project that I installed the xUnit.NET NuGet package to and wrote some test in it.  AFAIK I have set up everything correctly.

However, the Unit Tests pad is empty and I can't run any tests from Run -> Run Unit Tests.  I know a need a test runner, but I can only seem to find the one for Visual Studio.  Do I already have the runner and not know it?  I've never set up a testing environment before and am at a loss as to what else I need to do.

**Edit**

I have found the xunit.net console runner and installed it.  I can now run my tests from the console runner and can debug my tests from Run -> Debug Application...  However, my tests are still not recognized within monodevelop and still do not show up in the unit tests pad.

Answer (score 2):

I run my xUnit-tests under Monodevelop only with the Add-in.

I noticed when you have referenced another unit-test framework in your project, no tests will appear in the pad.

**Try to remove nunit.framework reference.**

Comment: I checked my project references and I don't have a reference to nunit.framework nor any references to any other nunit packages.

Comment: Can you see the tests in the console runner? [GitHub-Link](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/tree/master/src/xunit.console)

Comment: I actually did not have the console runner installed.  I don't why I couldn't find it earlier, but I now have the console runner and it will run my tests (thank goodness for the -noappdomain flag).  While this is definitely better than nothing, monodevelop still won't pick up my tests.

Comment: Great to hear! 

We are migrating all tests to xunit. Projects will also not show up in the pad if they have a reference to a project with nunit.framework reference (recursiv).

Comment: I don't think that's the problem.  This is a new project and the only references I have are to System, the project I'm testing, and Xunit.